# Is Spring bean thread safe for Jedis?

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety, jedis

We are not too sure if we apply Jedis pool correctly in order to achieve a Jedis thread-safe using Spring beans

```
<bean id="redisOnlineManager" class="com.app.online.RedisOnlineManager>
<property name="pool">
    <bean class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool">
        <constructor-arg value="redis://localhost:1234/1" />
    </bean>
</property>
```

```
private JedisPool pool;

public void setPool(JedisPool pool) {
    this.pool = pool;
}

private boolean exists(String key) {
    Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
    try {
        return jedis.exists(key);
    } finally {
        jedis.close();
    }
}
```

Did we implement Jedis pool correctly? does this code perform a thread-safe Jedis? If not, how should we use spring beans to make jedis threadsafe?

Please advise.. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if exists() method is thread safe? Is the class that you put above, is it RedisOnlineManager?

Comment: Yes, the code is from my RedisOnlineManager, i'm trying to ask if my above code which implemented jedis pool is it a thread-safe manner, 
According to https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started, it says "You can store the pool somewhere statically, it is thread-safe." do i need to create a static class? how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

What he is trying to say is that create the pool in a `spring singleton bean Or class with static method` for accessing pool. If you do either of it, you should be fine. What you have done in the code is that You are creating a pool for each instance of the ResourceManager and it can be improved like the following.

```
@Scope("singleton")
public class ResourceManager {

    private JedisPool pool ;

    public ResourceManager(){
        pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost");       
    }

    private boolean exists(String key) {
        Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
        try {
            return jedis.exists(key);
        } finally {
            jedis.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Your application context will not have the inner bean.

```
<bean id="redisOnlineManager" class="com.app.online.RedisOnlineManager/><!-- you dont need this in the application context if you are using annotations -->
```